# show some picture with delay with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show some pictures with a delay. My javascript code worked correctly but I want to convert my code to jQuery. However my jQuery code does not work correctly.

```
<div class="items hide">
    <img src="img/2.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="items hide">
    <img src="img/3jpg" />
</div>
<div class="items hide">
    <img src="img/1.jpg" />
</div>

<style>
    .items.hide {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .items.show {
        opacity: 1;
        animation: s3 2s ease-in-out;
    }
</style>

<script>
    items = document.getElementsByClassName('items');
    function show_item(i) {
        items[i].className = items[i].className.replace('hide', 'show');
    }
    for (j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
        setTimeout("show_item(" + j + ")", j * 300);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where is your jQuery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
$('.items').each(function(i, o){
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(o).addClass('show');
     }, i*300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    show_item(j);
}, j * 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, it would look likes to:

```
$('.item').each(function(i, o){
    $(o).addClass('show').delay(i * 300)
})
```